# Speech recognition for Pepper

Tags: pepper

I'm having trouble adding speech recognition on Pepper:

> [ERROR] behavior.box :_safeCallOfUserMethod:125 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorMasterProgram879924904:/Speech Reco._2: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/aldebaran/lib/python2.7/site-packages/albehavior.py", line 115, in _safeCallOfUserMethod     func()   File "", line 55, in onInput_onStart RuntimeError:    ALSpeechRecognition::setVocabulary      NuanceContext::addContext   A grammar named "modifiable_grammar" already exists.

This error keeps popping up, but I don't know why. I cannot find "modifiable_grammar" anywhere in the project.

Comment: you probably have another Speech Reco box running somewhere else on the robot ?

Comment: Can you create a new project and complete this tutorial without errors?
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/tutos/dialog_topic.html#aldialog-tuto

Comment: I checked the tutorial and dit it on my Pepper with the naoqi version 2.5.5. For me it's working. As JLS I think that is a problem with another speech Reco box that is running in parallele.

Comment: If the response solved your problem, please mark the response as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem and it took a lot of time to find the solution.

Use the pepper web-interface to change the robot language to another an then change to robot language again to the previous one.

[image: Print screen web-interface]